# Server for static webapp

Tags: node.js, heroku, static, webserver

I'm building a client side only webapp written in html5 & javascript, but I still need a server to server these files.

I'm using GruntJS for minifying/concatenating files and I plan to put the compiled website in a folder called `dist` or something similar.

So I only need a server that handle all requests to my website and load the corrisponding file from `/dist` so that requesting mysite/style.css loads mysite/dist/load.css.

I also need the server to handle `gzip` compression, http headers, mime types, cache control and error handling.

Since I'm already using nodejs I thought about a nodejs server like [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/), or [lactate](https://github.com/Weltschmerz/Lactate)

For the hosting I'm planning to use heroku (but maybe there are better services for my case), **which server do you advise**?

Answer (score 0):

Best way for hosting static files in Amazon-CDN, you may have simple logic on heroku basic-html page. 
You can prepare your own script, with compilation, concantenation, gzipping your files and put them with `s3cmd` to your s3-bucket on AWS. After that you need to link CDN to s3 bucket - that's all you application will be ready.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using grunt, and have thought about connect, you could always use the [grunt-connect](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-connect) plugin.

To install:

```
$ npm install grunt-connect
```

In your `grunt.js` file:

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    yourServer: {
      port: 1337,
      base: 'dist'
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect');
```